# Show a spinner after some wait time

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

My Angular application does a lot of Http Requests, so I'd like to display a spinner in order to notify the user that the application is working (and it's not "freeze"). So I have implemented the following interceptor:

```
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {finalize, timeout} from "rxjs/operators";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class LoadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  readonly TIMEOUT_VALUE = 10000;
  private requests: number = 0;

  constructor() {
  }

  public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.addRequest(request);
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        timeout(this.TIMEOUT_VALUE),
        finalize(() => this.removeRequest(request))
      );
  }

  private addRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
    this.requests++;
    if (this.requests === 1)
      this.present();
  }

  private present() {
    // show the spinner
  }

  private removeRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
    this.requests--;
    if (this.requests === 0)
      this.dismiss();
  }

  private dismiss() {
    // dismiss the spinner
  }

}
```

The above code displays a spinner when there is a pending request, and dismiss it when all the requests are completed. However, the requests often  return a value in under a second, therefore I'd like to display the spinner only when the requests take more the a second to respond.

My first approach was to have an interval in the constructor which check the number of pending request every second, and display/dismiss the spinner accordingly.

```
constructor() {
  Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
    if (this.requests === 1)
      this.present();
    if (this.requests === 0)
      this.dismiss();
  });
}
```

but this seems pretty ugly to me. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Tricky to work out the timing as there can be multiple requests. As such, the solution you had in mind is kind of random: if the interval happens to "tick" even 1 millisecond after a request was sent, the spinner will be displayed.

Comment: Yeah, that's another issue of my solution. I'm pretty sure there is a way to accomplish what I want by only using observables and their operator (maybe `debounce`?), but I'm pretty new to angular 2+ and I'm not able to use them well...

Answer (score 1):

Faced with same issue. Can not find a good solution and did it via debounceTime and counter.

Counter has been used for multiple requests.

**HttpLoadingInterceptor**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { finalize, } from 'rxjs/operators';

    import { LoadingIndicatorService } from '@app/services/loading-indicator.service';

    @Injectable()
    export class HttpLoadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
      constructor(public service: LoadingIndicatorService) {
      }

      intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this.service.show();

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
          finalize(() => this.service.hide())
        );
      }
    }
```

**LoadingIndicatorService**

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingIndicatorService {
  private counter = 0;
  private delay = 700;
  private isLoading = new Subject<boolean>();

  public stateChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() {
    this.isLoading.pipe(
      debounceTime(this.delay)
    ).subscribe(value => {
      if (value)
        this.counter++;
      else if (this.counter > 0) {
        this.counter--;
      }

      this.stateChanged.emit(this.counter > 0);
    });
  }

  public show() {
    this.isLoading.next(true);
  }
  public hide() {
    this.isLoading.next(false);
  }
}
```

**SpinnerComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingIndicatorService } from '@app/services/loading-indicator.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-spinner',
  templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.scss']
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  isBusy = false;
  subscription = null;

  constructor(
    private loadingIndicatorSvc: LoadingIndicatorService) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.subscription = this.loadingIndicatorSvc.stateChanged
      .subscribe(value => {
        if (this.isBusy !== value) {
          this.isBusy = value;

          document.body.style.overflow = this.isBusy
            ? 'hidden'
            : 'auto';
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same situation, and this is what I've used :

```
const DELAY_BEFORE_SHOWING_LOADER = 150; // ms

@Injectable()
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
private readonly loaderService = inject(LoaderService);

private totalRequests = 0;
private timeout!: NodeJS.Timeout;

/**
 * An HTTP interceptor that shows a loading indicator when requests are taking more than a specified delay.
 * @param request - The outgoing HTTP request.
 * @param next - The next interceptor in the chain.
 */
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // If this is the first request, set a timeout to show the loader
    if (this.totalRequests === 0) {
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.loaderService.showLoader(), DELAY_BEFORE_SHOWING_LOADER);
    }

    this.totalRequests++;

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        finalize(() => {
            this.totalRequests--;

            // If there are no more requests in progress, hide the loader
            if (this.totalRequests === 0) {
                this.loaderService.hideLoader();
                clearTimeout(this.timeout);
            }
        })
    );
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used `map`, `distinctUntilChanged` and `debounce` operators to achieve this.

`map` turns counter value to a boolean value so that we have only "on"/"off" values to deal with.

`distinctUntilChanged` throws away duplicates so spinner only receives changes of its state.

`debounce` handles the 1 second delay for spinner to be displayed.

Please see [this StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzyvtv) with a simulated request counter sequence.